# Html Agility Pack c#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to extract the number of items in stock (td5) from every product,
and having a problem that the system isnt writing 0 in the table if stock is empty.
My Code to extract the number would be:

```
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr[1]//td[5]");
```

With this I get product2 items in stock of course, any1 got a trick for me
to preprocess the table and fill the td´s with 0 or another way to 
grab the right numbers to the right product?

HTML:

```
<tr>
        <td class="data">product1</td>
        <td class="data" width="350">TEST1</td>
        <td class="data">27</td>
        <td class="data">ST</td>
        <td class="data"></td>
        <!-- <td class=data>`LIST-KWERT[j].value`</td> -->
        <td class="data"></td>
        <!-- <td class=data>`LIST-SEINM[j].value`</td> -->
        <!-- <td class=data>`LIST-SSPEM[j].value`</td> -->
    <td class="data"></td>
        <td class="data"></td>
        <td class="data"></td>
        <td class="data">999,9</td>
    </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="data">product2</td>
        <td class="data" width="350">TEST2</td>
        <td class="data">13</td>
        <td class="data">ST</td>
        <td class="data">21,000</td>
        <!-- <td class=data>`LIST-KWERT[j].value`</td> -->
        <td class="data"></td>
        <!-- <td class=data>`LIST-SEINM[j].value`</td> -->
        <!-- <td class=data>`LIST-SSPEM[j].value`</td> -->
    <td class="data">5,000</td>
        <td class="data">10,000</td>
        <td class="data">243</td>
        <td class="data">35,5</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I dont know much about htmlagilitypack but i think you can just test if the text within td5 `IsNullOrWhitespace` and set it zero accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get 5th td in each row you use this code:

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(input);
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var list = new List<Data>();
foreach (var node in root.SelectNodes("//tr//td[5]"))
{
    var price = node.InnerText.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? "no price" : node.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: That doesnt work this way :
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'value' of 'string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string)'

Comment: Use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(node.InnerText)` instead of `node.InnerText.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`